# jQuery Custom Validators

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm using the jQuery validation plugin and I'm looking to add some custom logic.  I have a series of checkboxes which have children checkboxes associated with them.  For certain (not all) of these parent checkboxes, I want to require that one of the children checkboxes is checked.  I have no issue hardcoding for this so I was adding a field like this to my DOM:

```
<input type="hidden" id="child_required_1" class="child_required_1" />
```

And then adding a custom validator like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('child_required_1', function(val, element) {
if($('#product_responses_1').length > 0) {
    if($('#product_responses_1').is(':checked')) {
        var count = $("input:checkbox:checked[id^='children_tags_1_']").length;

        if(count == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

return true;
}, 'You must select at least one child.');
```

This works perfectly fine.  But when I duplicate all of this and add "_2", only one of the validators seems to fire.  So from what I can gather, custom validators are unique per form?  If that's the case, how am I supposed to handle a situation like this where I may need 15-20 of these all showing in different places?  I don't want to just show one error.

I could also create a class rule but that doesn't solve my problem of creating multiple error labels and placing them in the relevant positions.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently having it on a hidden field didn't work, but when I removed the hidden fields and applied that class to the actual checkboxes themselves, it worked fine.  Not entirely sure why.